# Linking a Text Box to a variable?

Tags: c#, textbox

I would like to have direct access to the text inside a textbox on another form, so I added a public variable _txt to a form and added an event like so:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _txt = richTextBox1.Text;
}
```

But the form is loaded like this:

```
public FrmTextChild(string text)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _txt = text;
    richTextBox1.Text = _txt;
    Text = "Untitled.txt";
}
```

Is there a better way to directly link the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a property instead to read directly from your TextBox. That way you don't need an extra variable at all.

```
public string Text
{
  get
  {
    return richTextBox1.Text;
  }
}
```

Add a setter if you also want to be able to change the text.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should ever have forms reference each other's controls: when you change the lay out of one you will have to rewrite the code for the other. It is much better IMHO to store shared values in a separate class and have both forms reference *that*. Like so:

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public string SomeData{get;set;}
}

public class Form1:Form
{
   private DataContainer _container;
   public Form1(DataContainer container)
   {
      _container=container;
   }

   private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   { 
       _container.SomeData = richTextBox1.Text; 
   } 

   private void SpawnForm2()
   {
      var form2=new Form2(_container);
      form2.Show();
}

public class Form2:Form
{
   private DataContainer _container;
   public Form2(DataContainer container)
   {
     _container=container;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be setting the **Modifiers** property for the **TextBox** (or any other control you want to access) to **Protected Internal** and then open the second form, the **Owner** being the first form.

This way, you can later on access the control and its properties with something like this:

```
((Form1)this.Owner).textBox1.Text = "This is a message from the second form";
```